# Migration component webdynpro: Component is not yet ready to be converted

Tags: java, eclipse, netweaver, webdynpro

I'm using NWDS v7.31 and migrate the component in webdynpro application. On Cheat sheets - the Delete Implementation Coding from Interface Controller step, I have an error message:

> ```
> Unhandled event loop exception
>
> ObjectNotModifiableException: Attempt to modify read-only object: //WebDynpro/Controller:com.pwc.bc.registration.wd.parnr.approval.comp.PartnerNumberApprovalCompInterface!
>     at com.sap.ide.metamodel.core.DevelopmentObjectProxy._prepareForModify(DevelopmentObjectProxy.java:465)
>     at com.sap.ide.metamodel.webdynpro.implementation.AppClassProxy.setCodeBody(AppClassProxy.java:668)
>     at com.sap.ide.webdynpro.componentmigration.internal.actions.DeleteInterfaceControllerImplementationCodingAction.run(DeleteInterfaceControllerImplementationCodingAction.java:23)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.cheatsheets.ActionRunner.runAction(ActionRunner.java:86)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.cheatsheets.data.Action.execute(Action.java:100)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.cheatsheets.views.CoreItem.runExecutable(CoreItem.java:497)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.cheatsheets.views.CoreItem.runExecutable(CoreItem.java:492)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.cheatsheets.views.CheatSheetViewer.runPerformExecutable(CheatSheetViewer.java:1044)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.cheatsheets.views.CoreItem$1.linkActivated(CoreItem.java:89)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleActivate(AbstractHyperlink.java:233)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ImageHyperlink.handleActivate(ImageHyperlink.java:199)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleMouseUp(AbstractHyperlink.java:327)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.access$2(AbstractHyperlink.java:311)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink$4.handleEvent(AbstractHyperlink.java:125)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3910)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3503)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
>     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
> ```

Then, I uncheck read-only on folder properties and try again. But I still get an error message on Start migration step on Cheat sheets:

> Cannot start migration
>
> Component 'com.pwc.bc.registration.wd.ao.approval.comp.AOApprovalComponent' is not yet ready to be converted. Check the migration Cheat Sheet again to find out what needs to be changed.
>
> [image]

Please help me to review it and give me your thoughts.

Thanks,

Comment: Where are you migrating it?

Comment: @Suncatcher: I use SAP Enhancement Package 1 for SAP NetWeaver Developer Studio 7.3 SP18 PAT0002 on my computer to migrate WD java

Comment: so, you upgraded NWDS and want to go on development of component created in a previous version of NWDS?

Comment: @Suncatcher: yes,  I want to migrate WD project version 7.0 which is created on NWDS 7.0  to WD 7.4 on NWDS 7.31.